# TabControl.SelectedIndex is not working to switch tab control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a tabbed application where I used a tabcontrol with 4 tab items, i have a button in tab 4 where when i click on it I want to return to the first tab, I have tried TabControl.SelectedIndex = 0 but seems that it is not working, can you help ?

here is xaml

```
        <TabControl x:Name="TabAdd" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="535" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="645" BorderBrush="#FFE8E8E8" Padding="0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
            <TabItem x:Name="TabAddFlat" Header="Flat View" TabIndex="0"><!--IsSelected="True"-->
                <Grid Background="#FFFBFBFB" Margin="0">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridAddFlat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="466" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="407" Margin="109,10,0,0">
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="466" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="274" Source="Resources/F18.large - Copy.png" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="TabAddSide" Header="Side View" TabIndex="1">
                <TabItem.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFBFBFB" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </TabItem.Background>
                <Grid Background="#FFFBFBFB">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridAddSide" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="345" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" Margin="119,49,0,0">
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="343" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="394" Source="Resources/F1.large.png"/>                         
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem TabIndex="3" x:Name="TabAddInfo" Header="Customer Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" Margin="0,0,-78,0">
                <TabItem.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE8E8E8" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </TabItem.Background>
                <Grid Background="#FFFBFBFB">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridAddInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="466" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="407" Margin="109,10,0,0">                           
                        <TextBox x:Name="iaddress" MaxHeight="288" Height="95" Width="288" Controls:TextboxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Controls:TextboxHelper.Watermark="Address" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Padding="0" UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="27,246,92,125" AutoWordSelection="True" />

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem TabIndex="3" x:Name="TabAddReview" Header="Review" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" GotFocus="LoadAddReview">
                <TabItem.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFBFBFB" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </TabItem.Background>
                <Grid Background="#FFFBFBFB">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="15,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" Source="Resources/save-64.png" MouseLeftButtonDown="SaveFormAll"/>                       
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

and here is the c# code

```
    private void SaveFormAll(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TabAdd.SelectedIndex = 2;
    }
```

Comment: You have 2 tabs with TabIndex="3". Check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the image that you're using as a button, change MouseLeftButtonDown="SaveFormAll" to MouseLeftButtonUp="SaveFormAll" and try again. That should work.

The problem seems to be that your MouseLeftButtonDown handler is firing, but the MouseLeftButtonUp event immediately follows it and puts the focus back on the image, which means the last tab stays active. When I changed it to using MouseLeftButtonUp, it worked.